# Cambiar formato vector

Tags: r

Tengo un vector con este formato:

```
"X0_ARVI"      "X0_EEVI"      "X0_GGCI"      "X0_GNDV"      "X0_GRVI"      "X0_MCAR"     
  [7] "X0_MSAV"      "X0_NDRE"      "X0_NDVI"      "X0_RECL"      "X0_SAVI"      "X0_TCOS"     
 [13] "X10_ARVI"     "X10_EEVI"     "X10_GGCI"     "X10_GNDV"     "X10_GRVI"     "X10_MCAR"    
 [19] "X10_MSAV"     "X10_NDRE"     "X10_NDVI"     "X10_RECL"     "X10_SAVI"     "X10_TCOS"    
 [25] "X11_ARVI"     "X11_EEVI"     "X11_GGCI"     "X11_GNDV"     "X11_GRVI"     "X11_MCAR"
```

Y me gustaría obtener algo así:

```
X0_ARVI + X0_EEVI + X0_GGCI + X0_GNDV + X0_GRVI +X0_MCAR
```

Comment: ¿algo así; `paste0(tu_vector,  collapse=' + ')`?

Comment: El resultado es NA + NA + NA.... De momento no encuentro solución, estoy metiendolos a mano

Comment: Estás probando entonces con un vector que tiene valores NA, raro, por que en tu ejemplo no hay ¿Cómo esperas que se comporte la concatenación  cuando hay NA?

Comment: Vale, algo tuvo que salir mal, porque ahora si va, pero me sigue sin dejar meterlo en la función lm(), el vector directo así: lm(YIELD ~ predictors_ii, data = LAST_DFM), tengo que meterlo así: lm(YIELD ~ ., LAST_DFM[ , c("YIELD", predictors_i)]), sale este error  variable lengths differ (found for 'predictors_ii')

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de tu_vector con los predictores y de tu variable respuesta:

```
predictores <- paste0(tu_vector,  collapse=' + ')

# respuesta  (texto nombre columna)

texto_formula <- paste0(respuesta, predictores, collapse = " ~ ")

# debe ser algo así "YIELD ~ X0_ARVI + X0_EEVI + X0_GGCI + X0_GNDV + X0_GRVI +X0_MCAR"

formula <- as.formula(texto_formula) # convertimos texto en formula

lm(formula, data = LAST_DFM)
```